# react-native NavigationOptions header not showing

Tags: react-native

Here is a snippet of one of my React-Native class -

```
  class SignUp extends React.Component {

      static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        console.log('from header...');

        return {
          header: <SignUpHeader {...navigation.state.params} />,

          headerTransparent: true,
        };
      };

      constructor(props) {...}

      render(){....}

  export default withTheme(withNavigation(SignUp));
```

Here is a snippet of my react-navigation route.js -

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {

    SignUp: {
      screen:  SignUp,
    },
```

I have one HOC called withAppContext -

```
const withAppContext = Component => {
  return props => (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {value => (
        <Component {...props} value={value}>
          {props.children}
        </Component>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export {AppContext, withAppContext};
```

In this case, if I debug I can see the `'from header...'` is being logged from navigationOptions mentioned in the SignUp class.

However, if I wrap the change my route file to this -

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginRegisterSelection: {
      screen: LoginRegisterSelection,
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen:  withAppContext( SignUp),
    },
```

then the console log is not being printed. So it means that the naviagationOptions is not being called.

What I am possibly missing?

Please let me know if I can explain further?

Comment: Can you try putting your HOC at the export of your SignUpScreen ? It may be possible that the HOC is seen as the route and the SignUp screen is seen just as a child of withAppContext.

Comment: @Auticcat I have tried that already and did not work. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it working by moving the navigationOptions out of the SignUp component and putting it inside Route.js, like this.

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {

    SignUp: {
      screen:   withAppContext(SignUp),
       navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => {

    return {
      header: <SignUpHeader {...navigation.state.params} />,

      headerTransparent: true,
    };
  },
    },
   ........
```

However, I can not honestly explain why the earlier approach did not work.